# Android: Threaded drawing with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, draw, surfaceview

I'm trying to draw fractal on a SurfaceView within asynctask but I'm not sure how to perform it properly. My idea was to create surfaceview (in the main activity) which would contain progress bar, while separate thread would calculate which pixels will be drawn and store this on some kind of "buffer" (I use canvas for this). After that on the surfaceview result should be drawn (which should destroy spinning wheel of progress bar).

I've written this code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Complex constant;
private int bg_color, fg_color;
private static final int nMax = 30, rMax = 2;

private class JuliaThread extends AsyncTask<Complex, Void, Canvas> {
    private double re, im, w, h;
    private Complex sequence;
    private int i;
    private Canvas canv;
    private Paint p;
    private View m;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        m = (View) findViewById(R.id.sv);
        w = m.getWidth();
        h = m.getHeight();
        canv = new Canvas();
        p = new Paint();
    }
    @Override
    protected Canvas doInBackground(Complex... c) {
        for (double y=0; y<h; y++) {
            for (double x=0; x<w; x++) {
                re = (x/w)*3.0-1.5;
                im = -(y/h)*3.0-1.5;
                sequence = new Complex(re, im);
                for (i=1; i<=nMax; i++) {
                    sequence = sequence.square();
                    sequence.add(c[0]);
                    if (sequence.abs() > rMax) break;
                }
                if (i == nMax) p.setColor(fg_color);
                else p.setColor(bg_color);
                canv.drawLine((float)x, (float)y, (float)x, (float)y, p);
            }
        }
        return canv;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Canvas result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        m.draw(result);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    constant = new Complex(-0.391, -0.587);
    bg_color = Color.rgb(0, 0, 0);
    fg_color = Color.rgb(255, 255, 255);
    new JuliaThread().execute(constant);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainview" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </SurfaceView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. Could you explain me, what am I doing wrong and how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to obtain a `SurfaceHolder` from `SurfaceView` (by implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback`). Then do something like:

```
 final Canvas c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

 //---draw stuff--

 mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with asynctask...? I have created class extending SurfaceView, implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback but I don't know how to obtain this "mSurfaceHolder"